# Issue while publishing chart from excel to HTML using the xlHTML properties

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am trying to publish chart from excel to HTML file which I wish to further use in automated outlook mail.
below is the code:

```
Sub SaveChartWeb()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
wb.PublishObjects.Add _
    SourceType:=xlSourceChart, _
    Filename:=wb.Path & "\Sample2.htm", _
    Sheet:=ws.Name, _
    Source:="Chart 22", _
    HtmlType:=xlHtmlChart

wb.PublishObjects(1).Publish (True)
End Sub
```

when I run this code it throws the following errors:
"Run time 1004: This method or property is no longer supported in this version on excel"

I have tried all the possible combination of sourcetype and HTMLtype. when I use xlHTMLstatic it works but it publishes the entire sheet, which is not desired.

Comment: Perhaps move the chart from the worksheet to a chart and then publish it?

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comments, try this

```
Sub SaveChartWeb()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet

    With wb.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceChart, "C:\Sample.htm", ActiveChart.Name _
        , "", xlHtmlStatic, "", "")
        .Publish (True)
    End With
End Sub
```

You can always move the chart back to the sheet or close the original file without saving.