# Excel VBA - How to Save Named Charts, Tables, Ranges to HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, shapes, excel-charts

I'm struggling with this.
Here is my code, taken directly from MS Excel Documentation, but I keep getting a runtime 1004 error: Application-defined or object-defined error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.publishobjects.add

```
Sub publishsimple()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetcount As Long
sheetcount = Application.Sheets.Count
    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceChart, _
                    filename:="C:\Users\gblack\Downloads\testing.htm", _
                    Sheet:="Income, Worth, Age - Charts", Source:="Housing Stock", _
                    HtmlType:=xlHtmlChart, DivID:="", Title:="")
                        .Publish (True)
                        .AutoRepublish = False
    End With
End Sub
```

It will work with ranges, but doesn't seem to work with my charts. I'd rather not brute force exporting the ranges. There must be an elegant solution to saving my charts as HTML...

I'm open to using Python as well...

Comment: Most of the arguments of `PublishObjects` are optional... can you eliminate them one-at-a-time to figure out which is the culprit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194395/issue-while-publishing-chart-from-excel-to-html-using-the-xlhtml-properties

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195158/4717755), it may help. All of my tests for `PublishObjects.Add` haven't worked though, and I'm often getting an `Error 1004`. Puzzling.